# OS Error on running django-celery as daemon

Tags: python, django, django-celery, djcelery, celeryd

I need to run celery as a daemon. I am not using supervisor for this. Instead, I want to run celery with init on system start.

Here is the traceback of the error I am getting on starting the celery with `sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start`

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py:260: RemovedInDjango19Warning: "requires_model_validation" is deprecated in favor of "requires_system_checks".
  RemovedInDjango19Warning)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/halwee/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/management/commands/celery.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    ['{0[0]} {0[1]}'.format(argv)] + argv[2:],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 770, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 309, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 450, in setup_app_from_commandline
    os.chdir(workdir)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '"/var/www/html/hello"'
```

`/var/www/html/hello`
is the path of my root django application

I am following the tutorial from [here](http://www.arruda.blog.br/programacao/django-celery-in-daemon/).

I browsed through few answers on stackoverflow, etc and discovered that it might be a permission issue. But then I created a new group and a user and assigned this group to entire django root application. Issue still persist.

I have been stuck on this for like forever. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?